# Google cache api - caching urls with get parameters

Tags: javascript, java, html, caching

I am trying to cache my J2EE web application pages.
I manage to cache pages without any parameters. But for pages with GET parameters appended at the end of the URL, I can't seem to do so.

Can anyone guide me on how i can possibly cache a webpage with get parameters?

Below is my code:

```
const cacheName = 'sailors-cache';

const domainurl = '/The_Sailors_Application/Application/';

const cacheAssets = [
    domainurl + 'images/logo.png',
    domainurl + 'report-surveyor-generalinfo.html',
    domainurl + 'report-surveyor-timelog.html',
    domainurl + 'report-surveyor-acknowledgement.html',
    domainurl + 'report-surveyor-barge.html',
    domainurl + 'report-surveyor-bunker-condition.html',
    domainurl + 'report-surveyor-bunker-condition2.html',
    domainurl + 'report-surveyor-statement.html',
    domainurl + 'report-surveyor-sealchecklist.html',
    domainurl + 'report-surveyor-samplingreport.html',
    domainurl + 'report-surveyor-vessel-measurement-report.html',
    domainurl + 'report-surveyor-finalreport.html',
    domainurl + 'report-surveyor-mass-flow-meter.html',
    domainurl + 'report-surveyor-cargo.html',
    domainurl + 'report-surveyor-checklist.html',
    domainurl + 'report-surveyor-feedback.html',
    domainurl + 'report-pictures.html',
    domainurl + 'signature.html',

    domainurl + 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    domainurl + 'assets/css/normalize.css',
    domainurl + 'assets/css/font-awesome.min.css',
    domainurl + 'assets/css/themify-icons.css',
    domainurl + 'assets/scss/style.css',

    domainurl + 'assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.4.min.js',
    domainurl + 'assets/js/plugins.js',
    domainurl + 'assets/js/widgets.js'
];

    // Call Install Event
    self.addEventListener('install', e => {
      console.log('Service Worker: Installed');

      e.waitUntil(
        caches
          .open(cacheName)
          .then(cache => {
            console.log('Service Worker: Caching Files');
            cache.addAll(cacheAssets);
          })
          .then(() => self.skipWaiting())
      );
    });

    // Call Activate Event
    self.addEventListener('activate', e => {
      console.log('Service Worker: Activated');
      // Remove unwanted caches
      e.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
          return Promise.all(
            cacheNames.map(cache => {
              if (cache !== cacheName) {
                console.log('Service Worker: Clearing Old Cache');
                return caches.delete(cache);
              }
            })
          );
        })
      );
    });

    // Call Fetch Event
    self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
      console.log('Service Worker: Fetching');
      e.respondWith(fetch(e.request).catch(() => caches.match(e.request)));
    });
```

Example of a URL webpage i want to cache is this:
domainurl + 'report-surveyor-generalinfo.html?referenceNumber=YF-1223-19',

Thank you.

Comment: please paste your code that how you are adding URL to cache, what is expected URL and what is actual URL

Comment: @MuhammedImranHussain Hello, i edited

Comment: In your code context, your dynamic/parameter URL not cached. You need to match the url while fetching and if it doesn't match then put it into cache and then return so that next time it will serve from the cache. You will find details here https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker under "On network response" title

Comment: @MuhammedImranHussain sorry, i don't quite get it. can you explain again?

Comment: Your code cached report-surveyor-generalinfo.html but not report-surveyor-generalinfo.html?referenceNumber=YF-1223-19. I am assuming here referenceNumber is variable. So you can cache this URL on user interaction for example when clicked on the link or implement cache on network response. Both user interaction and cache on network response example mention in this doc https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker